# Valor fixo e único no Android no Unity 3D

Tags: c#, android, segurança, unity3d, mono

Estou tendo dificuldades em pegar um valor único e fixo no C#, preciso pegar um valor assim, por questões de segurança do meu software.

Já tentei utilizei o `SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier`, mas infelizmente ao desligar o *wifi* do dispositivo esse valor altera, o mesmo no Windows caso você conecte qualquer dispositivo no USB ele irá mudar também.

No Windows resolvi o problema pegando o numero físico do HD.

Já tentei o IMEI mas só funciona em dispositivos que tem suporte a *chip* de telefonia.

Como pegar esse valor no Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obrigado, acabei encontrando dessa forma também que aparentemente deu certo, mas estou testando em vários dispositivos aqui pra vê se essa solução é a estavel.

```
 AndroidJavaClass up = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

 AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = up.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity");

 AndroidJavaObject contentResolver = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject> ("getContentResolver");

 AndroidJavaClass secure = new AndroidJavaClass ("android.provider.Settings$Secure");


 string android_id = secure.CallStatic<string> ("getString", contentResolver, "android_id");
```

Answer (score 2):

Segundo essa [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7117667/221800) cada sistema tem sua forma. No Android a forma sugerida é:

```
android.telephony.getDeviceId()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Xamarin/DeviceId.cs).

Comment: o link parece errado.

Comment: @AlanVargas, aparentemente essa chamada sugerida pelo bigown é encapsulada na Unity pelo `SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier` que você já usa. Dá uma olhada na documentação: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html